# Woher stammt das Verb "flacken"

Tags: meaning, etymology

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/flacken_rumliegen_faulenzen) sagt

> **Bedeutung**
> [faul] daliegen
>
> **Herkunft**
> schwäbisch, bayrisch flacken, Herkunft ungeklärt

Im thüringischen und fränkischen Raum hat *flacken* eher die Bedeutung von "schmeißen".
Ein Beispielsatz wäre:

> Das kannste nur noch wegflacken.
>  <sup>Das kannste nur noch wegschmeißen.</sup>

Also woher stammt dieses Wort und welche Bedeutung hat es im Allgemeinen?

---

Laut [Grimm'schem Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Gliederung&hitlist=3836631&firsthit=0&textpattern=Edelknecht&lemmapattern=&patternlist=T:Edelknecht&lemid=GF05029) gibt hat es auch noch die Bedeutungen "schlagen".

> flacken, die wolle mit stäben schlagen und auflockern. Brosenius 161. nnl. vlaaken, von vlaak hürde zum wollschlagen.

Was ein lustiges Wort :-)

Comment: flacken im zweiten Sinn ist auch in Österreich gebräuchlich (z. B. sich auf das Sofa flacken).
Hier findet sich eine brauchbare Diskussion: http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=17337&lp=ende&lang=de

Comment: Dazu fallen mir zwei Sachen ein (die aber nicht zur Antwort reichen): lat. *flaccere* bedeutet etwa *schlaff sein*. In meinem Heimatdialekt (südliches Pfälzisch) kennt man *sich hinplacken*, was "sich faul hinlegen" bedeutet. Anlautendes *p* und *f* sind per erster Lautverschiebung verwandt.

Comment: Ich kannte nur die zweite Bedeutung. Und zwar aus der Drohung "... sonst kriegst du eine geflackt." Ich nahm immer an, daß es eine Verwandtschaft mit Flakgeschützen gab, durfte mich nun Dank deiner Frage aber eines besseren belehren lassen. Danke!

Comment: @painfulenglish: Bei Leo steht inzwischen leider: "Diese Diskussion existiert nicht oder wurde gelöscht." Davon unabhängig ist dein Beispiel mE ein denkbar unklarer Fall - ja, "sich auf das Sofa flacken" *könnte* im Sinn von "sich aufs Sofa werfen" gemeint sein und damit der zweiten Bedeutung entsprechen. Aber die erste Bedeutung erscheint hier ebenso naheliegend, indem man "sich aufs Sofa flacken" im Sinn von "sich (womöglich schwungvoll/kraftlos) hinlegen" interpretiert.

Answer (score 8):

Weiter oben in [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF05034#XGF05034) findet man:

> **flacken**, *segnescere, languescere, engl.* flag, *faul da liegen, insofern die Vorstellung von lau, warm auch in faul, träge übergeht, s. vorhin unter* flack, *näher steht vielleicht das lat.* flaccere, flaccescere. *Diese Bedeutung ist gut Oberdeutsch:* der flackt den ganzen Tag auf der Bärenhaut, flack dich hin, du Faulenzer! *Schmeller 1, 584;*

Demnach kommt das lateinische **[flaccere](http://www.frag-caesar.de/lateinwoerterbuch/flaccere-uebersetzung.html)** (erschlaffen, ermatten) sowohl in der Bedeutung als auch in der Aussprache dem süddeutschen Ausdruck "flacken" sehr nahe und ist seine wahrscheinliche Herkunft.

Answer (score -1):

Eine Flack ist ein wienerisches Wort für eine ziemlich feste Ohrfeige.

- "Wüst a Flack"
- "Wennst net umdrahst dann flack i da ane"

Comment: Das ist zwar interessant, beantwortet aber m.E. nicht die Frage nach der Herkunft des Begriffs. Kannst Du Deine Antwort vielleicht editieren und ergänzen?

Answer (score -3):

Ich würde vermuten, dass flacken im Sinne von faul herumliegen eine Zusammenziehung von flach + liegen ist. flacken im Sinne von schmeißen könnte mit "fliegen+machen" zusammenhängen. Das sind allerdings reine Vermutungen, ich habe nicht nachgeforscht, was zur Etymologie dieser Dialektwörter so gesagt wird.

Comment: Warum gibt es hier einen Downvote

Comment: @Emanuel Versteh ich auch nicht. Ein eventueller Kommentar wäre hier angebrachter gewesen. Ich wars jedenfalls nicht :)

Comment: Das ist reine Spekulation. Daher gebe ich hier -1.

Comment: Ich habe nicht gedownvotet, aber ich bin von der Vermutung hier auch nicht überzeugt. "Flacken" ist schließlich keineswegs begrenzt auf das *Liegen*; auch jemand, der herumsitzt, aber einfach die Zeit verstreichen lässt, "flackt" schließlich "herum".